# Probability that max cos(φ)x + sin(φ)y according to uniform distribution = (8,5)

Tags: probability, optimization, convex-optimization

max $x_2$ subject to

$x_1 - 2x_2 \le 0$
$2x_1 - 3x_2 \le 2$
$x_1 - x_2 \le 3$
$-x_1 + 2x_2 \le 2$
$-2x_1 + x_2 \le 0$

Optimal solution: (8, 5) --> $x_2 = 5$

Now assume that the objective is replaced with cos(φ)x + sin(φ)y, where φ is chosen at random, according to the uniform distribution on [0, 2π]. What is the probability to get, as an optimal solution, the same point as in the original problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you done the first bit yet? If not, try using the simplex algorithm.

Comment: @Esteemator hi, yes i solved the initial LO and found the optimal solution to be (8,5) just by graphic. 

Now I'm working on the trig part of the problem. What I'm thinking is that φ has to be between 0 and π/2 because outside of this, the objective function would lead to negative weights which would lead to an infeasible solution (the feasible domain was entirely positive).. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a two-variable linear programming and as OP said, I can try to answer this using the graphical technique mentioned. Here is the depicted feasible region (bounded by the red line) for the given constraints.

[image: Feasible Region]

And we know that the optimal solution must be located at one of the five corners. and now the desired solution is on the top right hand corner $(5, 8)$. Note that now the objective $V$ is

$$ V = \cos(\varphi)x_1 + \sin(\varphi)x_2 $$

Rearranging this family of object lines to the slope-intercept form gives

$$ x_2 = -\cot(\varphi)x_1 + \csc(\varphi)V$$

(ignore the point where $\sin(\varphi) = 0$ as they are measure $0$ anyway). Note that the $x_2$-intercept is $\csc(\varphi)V$. So the objective is strictly increasing with the $x_2$-intercept if and only if 
$$\sin(\varphi) > 0$$
And in such case, $V$ is maximized when the $x_2$-intercept is maximized, i.e. the objective line must be pushed upward to obtained the maximized $V$. The slope of the line $-\cot(\varphi)$. So now we can work with the 4 cases:

1. $\sin(\varphi) > 0, \cos(\varphi) > 0$:

In this case we push upward and the slope is negative. And it will always leads to the optimal solution we wanted. Since 
$$\varphi \in \left(0, \frac {\pi} {2}\right)$$
The probability in this case is $\displaystyle \frac {1} {4}$.

2. $\sin(\varphi) > 0, \cos(\varphi) < 0$:

In this case we push upward and the slope is positive. Then we will need the slope lies on 
$$ \left(0, \frac {1} {2}\right)$$ 
So we have
$$ 0 < -\cot(\varphi) < \frac {1} {2} \iff \tan(\varphi) < -2 
\iff \varphi \in \left(\frac {\pi} {2}, \tan^{-1}(-2) + \pi\right)
= \left(\frac {\pi} {2},  \pi - \tan^{-1}(2) \right)$$
So the probability in this case is 
$$\frac {1} {4}\left(\frac {\pi} {2} - \tan^{-1}(2) \right)$$

3. $\sin(\varphi) < 0, \cos(\varphi) > 0$:
   In this case we push downward and the slope is positive. Then we will need the slope to be larger than $1$. By similar solving, we have
   $$ \varphi \in \left(\frac {7\pi} {4}, 2\pi\right)$$
   and thus the probability in this case is $\displaystyle \frac {1} {8}$.
4. $\sin(\varphi) < 0, \cos(\varphi) < 0$:
   In the last case we push downward and the slope is negative. And the optimal solution will never located at our desired corner.

Summing the cases we have the probability

$$ \frac {1} {4} + \frac {1} {4}\left(\frac {\pi} {2} - \tan^{-1}(2) \right) +  \frac {1} {8} = \frac {1} {8}(3 + \pi - 2\tan^{-1}(2))$$